# UIImageView subview of a MapView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, mkmapview, addsubview

I must add an ImageView as subview of MapView. I can not do it by code, because the ImageView always ends up behind the mapView. I can not do it in IB because in the file's owner the UIImageView is always external respect to the mapView ( I tried several times).I am using Xcode 4.5. Can I add a UIImageView as subview of MapView?

this is the code in MapViewController.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *iphoneLegenda;
 @property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
```

in MapViewController.m

```
@synthesize iphoneLegenda;
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  //.....
    self.iphoneLegenda.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapView.bounds.origin.x, 
                            self.mapView.bounds.origin.y, 200, 100);

  //......

   [self.mapView addSubview:self.iphoneLegenda];
   [self.iphoneLegenda bringSubviewToFront:self.mapView];
  //.....
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a UIImageView inside a mapview?
This code is wrong [self.iphoneLegenda bringSubviewToFront:self.mapView];, it should be [self.mapView bringSubviewToFront:self.iphoneLegenda];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answers of AntonPalich and MashDup are the best way.
To add a subview inside mapView you have to add QuartzCore.framework and this is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
 layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
 layer.bounds = CGRectMake(mapView.frame.origin.x, mapView.frame.origin.y, 200, 100);
 [[mapView layer] addSublayer:layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the imageview on top of the map view, seeing as you are using an xib. the mapview is already on a view, just add the imageview in the xib like you have for the mapview and link that up. Make that alpha have 0 (better for animation later) in the xib. Then in your code, I assume you want a button or some sorts to turn it on. 
So change the line have iboutlet.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *iphoneLegenda;
```

Then an action to fade it in:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [iphoneLengenda setAlpha:1.];
    }];
```

Dont have to mess about setting frames etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about this scheme:

```
UIView
 - MKMapView
 - UIImageView
```

MKMapView will be same size as UIView and UIImageView will be always at top.